# JMockit: Special cases for reusing expectations

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have this setup:

```
@Tested
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Mocked
private MockedType1 mockedType1;

@Mocked
private MockedType2 mockedType2;

public class CustomExpectations extends Expectations {

    public CustomExpectations() {
        mockedType1.function1();
        result = result1;
        
        result1.function2();
        result = mockedType2;

        mockedType2.functionMockedType2();
        result = result2;
    }
}
```

Then, I have some tests that use this CustomExpectations class to do some setup, and then a more generic inline expectation with the rest of the code covered. The issue I'm finding is that, when the expectation

```
        mockedType2.functionMockedType2();
        result = result2;
```

is on the CustomExpectations class, the function call always returns null. If I move that expectation to the inline expectation, it works fine.

It is possible to do what I'm trying to do? I've tried to pass mockedType2 as a parameters to the CustomExpectations, but it still returns null.